# how to copy BitMatrix image file in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

For Multipart file -
   `Files.copy(file.inputstream, this.qrcodeLocation.resolve(fileName))`

how to copy file (bitmatrix type ) copy in `kotlin` or `java`. `file.inputstream` is accessible only for multipart file what is property for file.xxxx?.